# How to integrate $\int \frac{5^x dx}{5^x+3^x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I already know how to begin because I got the hint from an online calculator. 
The only thing is I can't derive the hint myself.

The hint is to write

$$5^x= \frac {\ln3}{\ln3-\ln5}(5^x+3^x)- \frac{1}{\ln3-\ln5}(\ln5 \cdot 5^x+ \ln3\cdot 3^x) $$

I don't have a clue on how to arrive at this hint. I know however how to continue after the hint.

Could some explain how one arrives at the hint?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of that approach.  I would approach the problem as follows:

To begin, divide the top and bottom by $3^x$ to get
$$
\int \frac{1}{1 + (5/3)^x}\,(5/3)^x dx
$$
Now, it suffices to apply a $u$-subsitution with $u = (5/3)^x$.  The integral is rewritten as
$$
\frac 1{\ln(5/3)} \int  \frac{1}{1 + u}\,du = \frac 1{\ln5 - \ln 3} \int  \frac{1}{1 + u}\,du
$$

---

As for how one arrives at the hint, I assume the thought process is as follows:

We would like to find coefficients $\alpha, \beta$ such that
$$
5^x = \alpha\,(5^x + 3^x) + \beta\,(\ln 5 \cdot 5^x + \ln 3\cdot 3^x)
$$
once we have computed such coefficients, we can express the integral as
$$
\int \frac{\alpha\,(5^x + 3^x) + \beta\,(\ln 5 \cdot 5^x + \ln 3\cdot 3^x)}{5^x + 3^x} dx =\\
\alpha\,x + \beta \ln|5^x + 3^x| + C
$$
With that in mind: we can set up the equation for these coefficients as
$$
5^x = \alpha\,(5^x + 3^x) + \beta\,(\ln 5 \cdot 5^x + \ln 3\cdot 3^x) \implies\\
5^x = (\alpha + \beta \ln 5) 5^x + (\alpha + \beta \ln 3) 3^x
$$
Setting coefficients equal, we can now solve the system of equations
$$
\alpha + \beta \ln 5 = 1\\
\alpha + \beta \ln 3 = 0
$$
to obtain the coefficients.

I'm sure there's a nice analogy to be made between this approach and the use of "partial fractions" for integrating rational expressions.

Comment: I like this, but it really doesn't answer the question.  The question asks about "Can someone explain how one arrives at the hint?"  You don't answer the question.  I'd be fine with a post that this is the second half of, the first part being answering the OP's question, whether you're a fan of the approach using the hint, or not.

Comment: @amWhy I admit that I interpreted the question fairly loosely.  My counterargument, however, is that it seems as though the asker is ultimately looking for some way to calculate the integral, hence the use of an online calculator.

Comment: @zahbaz Ah, you're right, I missed that (and would have written the integral differently myself).

Comment: @amWhy Noted, and I agree in retrospect.  For what it's worth, I am adding something about the computer's approach.

Comment: Okay, great, @Omnomnomnon, two approaches for the price of one!!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You're right. I was mainly looking for a way to calculate this integral. But it would be very much appreciated if I got some explanation to the given approach .

Comment: Do you guys have some tips for me on how to prepare for the exams? Because in one month and a half I have 5 exams (calculus, numbers and sets, linear algebra, general physics and pc practics). I have obligated myself to go to the library every weekday.

Comment: @AnonymousI That's not the best question for this forum, unfortunately, and it's a bit out of place in this comments section.  I think you would do well to ask about preparation in the [mathematics chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics), though.

Comment: Agreed, I'll do that. Thanks for the referral.

Comment: @AnonymousI with that being said: it's always good to consult those responsible for the exam.  If the exam is from a class, ask the professor.  If it's a standardized test, look up the website for the exam to find suggestions.